# how to stream large numpy array to s3 without extra data copy

Tags: python, numpy, amazon-s3

I have a large numpy array (~300GB) in memory that I would like to upload to s3, without having to make an extra in-memory copy or write to disk.

Currently, I am doing something like:

```
buffer = BytesIO()
np.save(buffer, large_np_arr)
buffer.seek(0)
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_client.upload_fileobj(buffer, bucket, key)
```

but I observed that this makes a copy of large_np_arr before uploading to s3.

Is there a way this BytesIO buffer can be limited in size and streamed to s3?

Alternatively, I suppose I could save the file to disk and then stream using smart-open, but ideally would like to avoid writing to disk if possible.

Comment: You could try to load one chunk into memory at a time, and use S3 multipart upload for each individual chunk.

Comment: Streaming the array directly would require treating its data buffer as a file-like object.  `save` creates a small header block with shape and dtype info, and then a byte copy of its data buffer.  It might be possible to steam a `memoryview` of that data buffer, but that's beyond my current level of expertise.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments.

Comment: @morfys - any luck accomplishing this?

Comment: @schuess, no, I switched my approach. I used bloscpack compression, which IIRC avoid an in-memory copy when compressing data by an order of magnitude:
https://pypi.org/project/bloscpack/